# Determining the region with data in a pcolor plot

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

I have a plot showing a map in a pcolor plot in Matlab R2012a/R2014a (=using the old graphic system) and want to implement panning and zooming.

Because the dataset is quite large (and needs to be interpolated from vector data), I would prefer not to plot the whole region at high resolution, but only a small fraction of it and then pan around. But I want to redo the plot once I pan out of this subregion, such that it contains the next subregion.

Is there some way to get the limits of the region with data in an `axes` object the same way I can the limits of the currently displayed region via `get(myAxes, '[XY]lim')`? This way I could replot only if necessary.

A workaround would be to store the limits inside a handles structure everytime I execute pcolor, but I wonder if there is something built ín for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

The region is not stored in the axes object itself, but in one of its children (the one containing the actual plot). It is if type `surface` for `pcolor` plots and `hggroup` for `contour` plots. So you can find it via

```
childHandle = plotfindall(myAxes, 'Type', 'surface')
```

This object contains all the data used for plotting in its properties `XData`, `YData` and `ZData`. The largest x value with data and already plotted (but maybe not in the visible range) can be determined via

```
xd = get(childHandle, 'XData');
maximumXWithData = max(xd(:));
```